# Compare Rows in DataTable

Tags: c#

I have 2 DataTables that looks like this:

```
YesterdaysTable  
AAA  
BBB  
CCC  
DDD  
EEE  
FFF  
GGG  
HHH  
III  
JJJ  

TodaysTable  
AAA  
BBB  
DDD  
FFF  
GGG  
HHH  
III  
JJJ
```

As you can see, `TodaysTable` does not contain CCC & EEE. When I try to find the differences to let me know what's in `YesterdaysTable` that does not exist in `TodaysTable` using the following code, I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: the source contains no DataRows

but there **are** rows in my source:

```
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
dtSource = yesterdaysTable.AsEnumerable().Except(todaysTable.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();

var difference = yesterdaysTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Apps")).Except(todaysTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Apps")));

if (difference.Any())
{
    DataTable Table3 = (from row in todaysTable.AsEnumerable()
                        join app in difference on row.Field<string>("Apps") equals app
                        select row).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

I get the same error when I use similar code:

```
var appsNotInB = yesterdaysTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Apps"))
        .Except(todaysTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Apps")));

var TableC = (from row in yesterdaysTable.AsEnumerable()
              join id in appsNotInB on row.Field<string>("Apps") equals id
              select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

I went as far as trying to write a nested for-loop to try to put the differences into a `List<string>` object, to no avail:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yesterdaysTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < todaysTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        if (yesterdaysTable.Rows[i]["Apps"].ToString() != todaysTable.Rows[j]["Apps"].ToString())
        {
            //lstNoMatch.Add(yesterdaysTable.Rows[i]["Apps"].ToString());
            lstNoMatch.Add(todaysTable.Rows[j]["Apps"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different solutions but nothing is working and I don't want the post to be unnecessarily long. I've hit a dead-end :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: This LINQ statement:

DataTable Table3 = (from row in todaysTable.AsEnumerable()
                                    join app in difference
                                    on row.Field<string>("Apps") equals app
                                    select row).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: `CopyToDataTable` throws this exception if the query didnt return any rows. One reason why i avoid that method. You could avoid with pre-checking with `query.Any()`. But that executes it twice. So classic `foreach` to add the rows is to be preferred.

Comment: Then what should I rather be doing / using? I'm at a loss of understanding why no rows are returned because both tables I'm referencing contain DataRows

Comment: @GrammatonCleric: the `Any` check in your first approach is useless because you are checking something completely different than what you are selecting afterwards(the `Except` query first and then the `Join` select).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Even if I don't use the `Any` method, it throws the same exception. I actually applied your solution to this as it's a question you answered on a different thread at some point

Comment: Is that the only column in these tables?

Comment: Yes, there's only 1 column in each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CopyToDataTable` throws this exception if the query didnt return any rows. One reason why i avoid that method. You could avoid the exception with pre-checking with `query.Any()`. But that executes it twice. So a `foreach` to add the rows is to be preferred.

> I try to find the differences to let me know what's in
>   `YesterdaysTable` that does not exist in `TodaysTable`

Then this query does the job (you've done this correctly):

```
var onlyYesterdayApps = yesterdaysTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Apps"))
    .Except(todaysTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Apps")));
```

If you want the rows in a third table you have to use `YesterdaysTable` as source:

```
DataTable result = yesterdaysTable.Clone(); // empty table with same columns
var yesterdayRows = from r in yesterdaysTable.AsEnumerable()
                    join app in onlyYesterdayApps
                    on r.Field<string>("Apps") equals app
                    select r;
foreach(DataRow row in yesterdayRows)
    result.ImportRow(row); // import rows if the query above yielded rows
```

Just the final `foreach` will execute the two queries(which are actually merged to one).

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. It's all I really need to proceed. Thanks a lot! :)